# How to pass Class Object Parameter in C# Web Service .net 1.1

Tags: .net, class, object, web, service

I am trying to create one web service that accept object as parameter with .net 1.1. When I create class object and call that web method with created object parameter, I have got "No overload for method 'Amount' takes '3' arguments" error.

// Here is my web method

```
[WebMethod]
public void Deposit(Amount amount)
{
    string tranAmount;
    string tranCurrency;
    string exchangeAmt;

    try
    {
        tranAmount = amount.amount;
        tranCurrency = amount.currency;
        exchangeAmt = amount.amt.amt;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Utility.LogMsg(ex.Message);
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Amount
{
    private string _amount;
    private string _currency;
    private AmountTest _amtTest;

    public Amount()
    {
    }

    public Amount(string strAmount,string strCurrency, string strAmt)
    {
        amount = strAmount;
        currency = strCurrency;
        amt = new AmountTest(strAmt);
    }

    public string amount
    {           
        get 
        {
            return _amount;
        }
        set 
        {
            _amount = value;
        }
    }

    public string currency
    {           
        get 
        {
            return _currency;
        }
        set 
        {
            _currency = value;
        }
    }

    public AmountTest amt
    {           
        get 
        {
            return _amtTest;
        }
        set 
        {
            _amtTest = value;
        }
    }

}

[Serializable]
public class AmountTest
{
    private string _amt;
    public string amt
    {

        get 
        {
            return _amt;
        }
        set 
        {
            _amt = value;
        }
    }

    public AmountTest()
    {
    }

    public AmountTest(string strAmt)
    {
        amt = strAmt;
    }
}
```

// Here is my client call

```
webservice service = new webservice();
Amount amount = new Amount("10","USD","101"); // Error happen here
service.Deposit(amount);
```

Please clarify how to correct them. Thanks in advance.